# How can I get to this backend screen of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, website-admin

This may sound dumb, but I am [watching this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpBGhFkT3_s), how do I get to that screen that appears at 1:00? <sup>snapshot bellow</sup>

[image: youtube screenshot]

I feel like it's probably more simple than I am making it out to be...
Do I need to buy a host or something?
I signed up for a wordpress.org account but don't see this section anywhere on the site

I am so close to turning my page into a wordpress just cant figure out this small thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/

Then you will have an entry for WP Static HTML in your Settings menu.